# RecyclerView ItemDecoration Spacing and Span

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a GridSpacingItemDecoration class that manages spacing and spans.
here is the code:

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
{
    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;
    private boolean rtl;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(boolean rtl, int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge)
    {
        this.rtl = rtl;
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge)
        {
            if (rtl)
            {
                outRect.right = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.left = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            }else {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            }

            if (position < spanCount)
            { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else
        {
            if (rtl){
                outRect.right = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.left = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            }else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            }

            if (position >= spanCount)
            {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well when i want to have one or more columns. (shown in pictures below - all spacing and span works)
[image]
[image]
The problem is that i want to use a RecyclerView that has different ViewTypes with different spanCount. here is how i tried to do it:
defined in class:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> type = new ArrayList<>();

private int getTypeForPosition(int position)
{
    return type.get(position);
}

private final int HEADER = 0;
private final int CHILD = 1;
private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

defined in method:

```
type.add(HEADER);
type.add(CHILD);
type.add(CHILD);
type.add(HEADER);
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
@Override
public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    switch(getTypeForPosition(position)) {
        case HEADER:
            return 2;
        default:
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(true, 1, dpToPx(8), true));
ClassAdapter classAdapter = new ClassAdapter(getContext(), classes);
recyclerView.setAdapter(classAdapter);
```

here is the result:
[image]

The problem is: the space between two columns in the same row (shown in picture). it seems to be 16, twice what i have choosed.
Question: How to customize GridSpacingItemDecoration class to have same space between all items?

Comment: two columns adding each other space thats why they seen wider,  you have add check when you are adding these two columns and pass them half distance which you have given now.

Comment: @jiteshmohite I know they are adding each other space, but can't find a solution to change the class to actually work for different ViewHolder with different spans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my proposition:

```
class SearchResultItemDecoration(val space: Int, val NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect?, view: View?, parent: RecyclerView?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        addSpaceToView(outRect, parent?.getChildAdapterPosition(view), parent)
    }

    private fun addSpaceToView(outRect: Rect?, position: Int?, parent: RecyclerView?) {
        if (position == null || parent == null)
            return

        val grid = parent.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager
        val spanSize = grid.spanSizeLookup.getSpanSize(position)

        if (spanSize == NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS) {
            outRect?.right = space
        } else {
            var allSpanSize = 0
            for (i: Int in IntRange(0, position)) {
                allSpanSize += grid.spanSizeLookup.getSpanSize(i)
            }
            val currentModuloResult = allSpanSize % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
            if (currentModuloResult == 0) {
                outRect?.right = space
            }
        }
        outRect?.left = space
        outRect?.top = space
    }
}
```

The code is written in Kotlin, but I hope it's enough clear to read it as a Java developer ;) So, The main assumption is to always add sapce to top and left side of item. Now, we onnly need to wory to add space on the right side, to do this we need to know which item is on the right of the row.

`spanSize` is value that holds information about how many columns current view is taking. If it takes all columns of the row then obviously we also wanto to add right space.

That was a simple situation. Now if we want to add right space to an item, which is also on the right side of `RecycelrView` we need to calculate it. `allSpanSize` is an value which doesn't count item position, but item span size. In that way all we need to do now is to do simple math with modulo operation. If the rest of the division is 0 we now that current item is on the right.

I know, that's maybe not the best solution, becouse when you have a lot of items in `RecycelrView` it can take some time to calculate. To prevent it, you could story some arrayList, which holds position of the view and `allSpanSize` for given item.

Comment: You know that you can remove those `?` on `outRect`, `view`, etc, right? Even though those are framework methods its kind of guaranteed that they will not be `null`. Android Studio is just generating the safe version, but you should remove the `?` whenever possible.

Comment: Also I do not think that it is a good idea to loop `IntRange(0, position)`, since you could have _a lot_ of items and this would run at every frame for every visible item. This coupled with `spanSizeLookup.getSpanSize()`, which could also be a slightly more expensive operation than a simple returned integer, could lead to serious performance issues.

Comment: @Panczur nice it worked perfectly, i re-wrote the code in java. could you take a look at the code in the pictures below to see if it's completely correct. i'm not so familiar with kotlin and might have made some mistakes.
1. http://imgur.com/a/Op9Ah
2. http://imgur.com/a/A1W4Z

Answer (score 27):

The way to do this is to read the layout parameters of the view.

```
GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams params =
        (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParameters()
```

Those [layout parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.html) have the following properties:

```
// Returns the current span index of this View.
int getSpanIndex()

// Returns the number of spans occupied by this View.
int getSpanSize()
```

This way you can check in *which column* a view is and how many columns it *spans*.

- If it is in column `0` you apply the full offset on the start side, else only half
- If `spanIndex + spanSize` equals `spanCount` (it occupies the last column) you apply the full offset on the end, else only half.

For better reusability you should also consider using

```
((GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).getSpanCount()
```

to get the count of total spans instead of setting it in the constructor. This way you can dynamically change / update the span count and it will still work.

Please don't forget to check `instanceof` before casting and throwing proper exceptions or something ;)

---

Following these instructions to the letter, we end up with the following decoration:

```
class GridSpanDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
  private final int padding;

  public GridSpanDecoration(int padding) {
    this.padding = padding;
  }

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();
    int spanCount = gridLayoutManager.getSpanCount();

    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams params = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

    int spanIndex = params.getSpanIndex();
    int spanSize = params.getSpanSize();

    // If it is in column 0 you apply the full offset on the start side, else only half
    if (spanIndex == 0) {
      outRect.left = padding;
    } else {
      outRect.left = padding / 2;
    }

    // If spanIndex + spanSize equals spanCount (it occupies the last column) you apply the full offset on the end, else only half.
    if (spanIndex + spanSize == spanCount) {
      outRect.right = padding;
    } else {
      outRect.right = padding / 2;
    }

    // just add some vertical padding as well
    outRect.top = padding / 2;
    outRect.bottom = padding / 2;

    if(isLayoutRTL(parent)) {
      int tmp = outRect.left;
      outRect.left = outRect.right;
      outRect.right = tmp;
    }
  }

  @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "WrongConstant"})
  private static boolean isLayoutRTL(RecyclerView parent) {
    return parent.getLayoutDirection() == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
  }
}
```

Which allows for an arbitrary amount of columns and will align them correctly.

[image: Grid Span Decoration]

Comment: could you update the class, i did what you said but didn't work when i had three columns per row. not sure what i have done wrong. however there wasn't any problem with two columns per row.

Comment: how sould i change these lines: GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
  glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() because ((GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).getSpanCount() will always return 3.

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi I will have a look later. I meant that you should remove the spanCount from the constructor of `GridSpacingItemDecoration` and read it instead from the layoutmanager as shown. This is just for greater flexibility

Comment: I know i need to remove the constructor,but then this line won't work glm.setSpanSizeLookup().

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi I'm talking about the constructor of your _decoration_ where you currently pass in `spanCount`

Comment: I already removed that and using int spanCount = ((GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).getSpanCount(); in getItemOffsets instead. Isn't that correct? but it always returns 3 in the log.

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi I updated the answer with working sample code

Comment: nice. just a small problem. could you update the answer to support rtl, it doesn't work when the layout orientation is rtl. and the top padding for item 0 should be outRect.top = padding not outRect.top = padding/2.

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi I added RTL support. For additional top and bottom padding I suggest you use a different approach, e.g. adding padding to the recyclerview with `clipToPadding=false`. Adding those paddings to the decoration shown would complicate things and is not too easily possible, given that this decoration supports arbitrary columns and spans.

Comment: unfortunately there is a bug. my recycler view has drag and drop enabled. and after drag and drop margins are messed up but everything works with Panczur solution. could you enable drag and drop and check it please.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi Since Panczurs approach seems to work you should try to just apply the full offset to one side, instead of half on each